# Reach Adjust on Shimano hydraulic brake levers for MTB flat bar

Tags: shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake

I am thinking to install Shimano BL-MT200 (or the BL-M315 depending on availability) on my son's bike (my son is 7 years old).  The bike currently has short reach brake levers for the current mechanical brake set.

I want to make sure the lever reach is going to be OK.  Shimano lists these brake levers as having "Reach Adjust", however neither the manual nor the dealer manual have any mention on how this is done.  (which is unexpected because the Shimano dealer manuals are usually quite good)

How is the reach adjusted on these levers and is it likely the reach can be adjusted sufficiently for a child's hand?

Comment: (Reach Adjust is a brand name used by Shimano)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reach adjust is though a small (2.5mm?) hex key on the 'inside' of the lever. The MT400's definitely have it.

The amount of reach adjustment is quite wide, On my MT400's, from memory you can adjust it down until the lever very nearly hits the bars before the brakes are fully applied, so will be as good as can be for a child. Higher end brakes have better performance and adjustments like free stroke, that might help those small hands, but the price/performance/reliability of the MT400's or 315's is impossible to beat.

[image: https://www.scenebyhird.com/Bike/BrakeLever.jpg]]

Comment: Thanks!  I had a look at my own MT400's and spotted them.  Still strange that the dealer manual doesn't mention it.  I assume I adjust it before I fill everything up with mineral oil?

Comment: Dealer's manual 2 on [Shimano website](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/acera-m390/BL-MT200.html) has it on page 64. Can't have the consumer finding that detail too easily, apparently!

Comment: @Swifty that's great thanks!  Dealer manual 2 is not listed on all other brake lever product pages, probably why I missed it.

Comment: @Superman.Lopez when bleeding/refilling adjust the reach out as far as the screw will take it. Once working then adjust reach in to what you want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COLd57jDvOE

Comment: @Superman.Lopez I don't think it's strictly necessary to mess with the reach for bleeding. The screw only changes the location of the lever blade's pivot and has nothing to do with the internals. I've stripped one of those tiny screws before so it would be best to use it as little as possible.